# in org-mode, how to delay the display of SOME scheduled tasks until the day of?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'd like to delay the display of some of my scheduled tasks until the day of. But for other scheduled tasks, I'd like them to display a couple days in advance as per default.

From the manual:

> If you want to delay the display of this task in the agenda, use `SCHEDULED: <2004-12-25 Sat -2d>`: the task is still scheduled on the 25th but will appear two days later. In case the task contains a repeater, the delay is considered to affect all occurrences; if you want the delay to only affect the first scheduled occurrence of the task, use `--2d` instead. See `org-scheduled-delay-days` and `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-delay-if-deadline` for details on how to control this globally or per agenda.

So that's a way to delay the display of tasks in the agenda until two days AFTER the scheduled task. But I want certain tasks to display the day they occur but not before.

I tried `SCHEDULED: <2015-09-13 Sun -0d>` but that didn't work... how do I ask Emacs to delay the display of certain scheduled tasks, specifying on a per-task basis?

UPDATE: Here's what my org-agenda looks like:

[image: agenda]

Below are the contents of my org-mode file (or see the actual org file [here](http://incandescentman.github.io/org-agenda-test-file.org)).

```
* dailies - week of <2015-09-14 Mon> 
*** COMMITTED <2015-09-16 Wed> [0%]
***** TODO meditate 
        SCHEDULED: <2015-09-16 Wed> 
***** TODO morning pages 
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-16 Wed> 

*** COMMITTED <2015-09-17 Thu> [0%]
***** TODO wake up 8:30am
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-17 Thu 8:30am>
***** TODO blue light therapy
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-17 Thu 8:31am>
***** TODO meditate 
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-17 Thu> 
***** TODO morning pages 
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-17 Thu>
***** TODO lights out by 12:30am
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-17 Thu 11:59pm> 

*** COMMITTED <2015-09-18 Fri> [0%]
***** TODO wake up 8:30am
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri 8:30am>
***** TODO blue light therapy
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri 8:31am>
***** TODO meditate 
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri> 
***** TODO morning pages 
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri>
***** TODO lights out by 12:30am
      SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri 11:59pm>
```

BTW, results of `C-h v RET org-scheduled-delay-days`:

```
org-scheduled-delay-days is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is 0
```

In my .emacs:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '(
    (sequence "TODO" "STARTED" "|" "DONE! :-)")
    (sequence "MISSED" "|" "DONE! :-)")
    (sequence "COMMITTED" "RESULTS" "|")
(sequence "WAITING" "DAILIES" "WEEKLIES" "MONTHLIES" "QUARTERLIES" "YEARLIES" "GOALS" "SOMEDAY" "|") 
    ))
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but isn't that the functionality out of the box?  When I schedule something for a day (without the `-0d` notation), it doesn't show up in the agenda until that day.

Comment: I agree that this seems to work out of the box.  But, if the entry also has a deadline that can trump the schedule delay (depending on the value of `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled`).

Comment: @Dan erikstokes Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I added a screenshot and my org-mode file so you can inspect. Thanks!

Comment: @incandescentman: try starting emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q` from the command line).

Comment: @Dan This is indeed fixed when I launch Emacs without my init file. Any leads on what I can look for to figure out what's causing the nonstandard behavior?

Comment: Sorry, don't know.  In this circumstance, your best bet is probably to bisect your init file: comment out the last half, then comment out the half of the half that didn't work, then the half of the half of the half, and so on until you identify what's causing the problem.  It's less time-consuming than it sounds, and, unless you have a pretty good idea what's causing the problem, less frustrating than trying to guess.